# garlicjs-rails - alert user if localStorage data is loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, local-storage

garlicjs-rails has a callback called 'onRetrieve'.  Im thinking thats my solution to highlighting which fields are from localStorage.  I have an alert in here now just for debugging but would change this to add a class to those fields that are getting their data from localStorage (ie editing existing data where some fields are in the DB and some either are not or have been changed).

this script is from the garlicjs.js site

```
   $( 'input.no_good' ).garlic( {
      onRetrieve: function ( elem, retrievedValue ) {
      console.log( 'The retrieved value for ' + elem.name() + ' is : ' + retrievedValue );
     }
    } );
```

this is what I am attempting to use

```
  $("input#user_certificatenumber").garlic onRetrieve: (elem, retrievedValue) ->
    alert "The retrieved value for " + elem.name() + " is : " + retrievedValue
```

Nothing is happening for me...  What Im expecting is that if the element with id user_certificatenumber is retrieved from the localStorage that '.garlic onRetrieve' will trigger and run the function.  Not so.

I hoping I can get two things out of asking this question:  Learn javascript a bit better and figure out how to watch all fields in a form, not just one, and then use js to add class and color up those inputs that were retrieved from the localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `data-persist="garlic"` on your form ?

If so, your `onRetrieve` listener is not applied to your form elements, because form is already binded by data-persist.

Just add your lines to the entire form (without data-persist) to bind Garlic on its elems AND register onRetrieve listener on each fields

```
$("#yourformid").garlic onRetrieve: (elem, retrievedValue) ->
    alert "The retrieved value for " + elem.name() + " is : " + retrievedValue
```

Best

Comment: So, I removed data-persist from my form, and created the coffeescript following your example with my forms id...but, the alert is never hit.  Do I need to set something on each element?

Comment: `onRetrieve` is called on page load on every field that has Garlic persisted data. If you use `$("#onfieldis").garlic('retrieve');` does the `onRetrieve` listener called?

Comment: Yup.  I changed it to hit every input in the form using $("form.form-horizontal").garlic('retrieve');.  This works...but, still unsure how to tag only those inputs who's displayed value is from garlic (and NOT the database).

Comment: Not sure what I am trying to do is feasible.  Every field is stored in local storage, whether its in the DB or only in local.  I would have to check if the value displayed is different than the database value, and then set a class.  Doable, but is it worth it...  Does seem like a function garlic should have though...if I come up with something solid Ill do a pull request.

Comment: When using the alert you have above...the data seems to be loaded from local, but the alert is never hit.  Just, as an update:  I don't want user to get confused and think that data displayed in a form is in the database when it is actually only loaded from local storage...I want to alert the user that 'these fields are NOT in the database"...  That is why I am trying to use the onRetrieve callback.  Any ideas?

Comment: And, not all fields are repopulating from local storage...only some...and sometimes they are not loading the last entered value.

Comment: It appears this function has been added recently to garlic.js.  There is now a conflict manager, do bundle open garlic's-rails and open up garlic.js ... do a search for 'conflictManager'.